# Can't get Manager().dict() value with custom class from different modules

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-module

I want to share some custom class objects among different processes by using Manager().dict().

If I run test.py, I can only see the output "write", no session output. actually the program will wait at `session = sessions[_id]` forever.

If I run test2.py, I can see the output "write" and session output normally.

```
write
<__main__.Session object at 0x10a27b128>
```

I think the problem is the custom class, if I store some integer or string, it will work.

test.py

```
import time
from test2 import write_data

for i in range(1000):
    write_data(0, 'hello')
```

test2.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

class Session(object):
    def __init__(self, sid, data):
        self.session_id = sid
        self.data = data

def write_data(_id, data):
    print('write')
    if _id not in sessions:
        sessions[_id] = Session(_id, data)
    session = sessions[_id]
    print(session)

mgr = Manager()
sessions = mgr.dict()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_data(0, 'hello')
```

Comment: When you call `write_data` from test.py only the write_data function is executed. The line `sessions = mgr.dict()` do *not* get executed when you call `write_data`from test.py

Comment: @äymm hi, ```from test2 import write_data``` will run the ```sessions = mgr.dict()```

Comment: I might be wrong then. Have you tried adding additional debug outputs at the beginning of `write_data`, such as `print(_id, data, sessions, _id in sessions)`?

Comment: @äymm yes I have tried these, and very weird, ```print(sessions)``` is right,  and also ```_id in sessions``` is True, just can't get the value.

Comment: Can you add the `__str__` and `__repr__` magic methods to `Session` and return something akin to `"Session with ID: " + str(self.session_id)"`?